# Is it possible to deploy iOS apps through web in 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

Im trying to deploy an app over the air in xcode but everytime i redirect the user to the websites the app downloads but shows that cannot be installed by the times.

So my question is, is It possible to deploy IPAs over the air trhrough a website in 2018 with any kind of license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing app for your organization then,

What you are looking for is termed as

> Apple Developer Enterprise Program

Here you can find details about the membership :
[Apple Develope Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

> Deploy In-house Apps

Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS, watchOS, and tvOS apps within your organization. Securely host and deploy apps to your employees' devices.

You can read different membership type at  : https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Is It 100% reliable for this kind of work? I mean without adding every iuid and 100% remote?

Comment: @DiegoRosales -  Apple Developer Enterprise Program is only solution to your question.

Comment: if you want to distribute your app to all user why not app store then ?

Comment: Is for infernal use of an enterprise and even though It has a security system they plan to publish múltiple apps and apps store review doesnt look that great for my boss

Comment: If you are looking to distribute within your organization then you should go with this Program, You must provide your Provisioning profile , device with your provisioning profile are only allowed to download your app, yes you can distribute that too